# AS3 Shoutcast stream doesn't work on server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, shoutcast, internet-radio

There's a code that works while I'm trying it in FLASH. It streams shoutcast :

```
var soundOBJ : Sound = new Sound();
soundOBJ.load(new URLRequest("http://176.9.42.221:8000/"));
soundOBJ.play( );
```

When I publish it and deliver on server, shoutcast doesn't stream! Can someone advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a semicolon at the end of your URL.

```
soundOBJ.load(new URLRequest("http://176.9.42.221:8000/;"));
```

SHOUTcast servers will return an admin panel if they detect "Mozilla" in your User-Agent.  This gets around the problem.